# How to create a service in Android that can't be killed by Advanced Task Killer

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-ndk, android-manifest

I create a security application just like Mcafee wave secure.
My application is listening for SMS command and doing some action when the command is match, so I create a form with another service for listening the SMS.

Here's the main form:

```
public static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
ArrayList<String> messageList;
ArrayAdapter< String> adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //untuk mendisable notification area
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MainButtonAbout=(Button) findViewById(R.id.MainbuttonAbout);
    MainButtonHelp=(Button) findViewById(R.id.MainbuttonHelp);
    MainButtonWizard=(Button) findViewById(R.id.MainbuttonWizard);
    MainButtonOption=(Button) findViewById(R.id.MainbuttonOption);
    MainCheckBoxActive=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.MaincheckBoxActive);

    MainButtonAbout.setOnClickListener(this);
    MainButtonHelp.setOnClickListener(this);
    MainButtonWizard.setOnClickListener(this);
    MainButtonOption.setOnClickListener(this);

    startService(new Intent(MainForm.this, ListenSMSservice.class));

    MainCheckBoxActive.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (buttonView.isChecked())
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainForm.this, "Your Device is Protected Now!!", 1).show();              
                startService(new Intent(MainForm.this, ListenSMSservice.class));
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainForm.this, "Your Device is not Protected Now!!", 1).show();
                stopService(new Intent(MainForm.this, ListenSMSservice.class));
            }
        }
    });

}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.MainbuttonAbout:
        Intent GoToAbout= new Intent(this,AboutForm.class);
        startActivity(GoToAbout);
        break;
    case R.id.MainbuttonHelp:
        Intent GoToHelp= new Intent(this,HelpForm.class);
        startActivity(GoToHelp);
        break;
    case R.id.MainbuttonWizard:
        Intent GoToWizard1= new Intent(this,WizardForm1.class);
        startActivity(GoToWizard1);
        break;
    case R.id.MainbuttonOption:
        Intent GoToOption= new Intent(this,OptionForm.class);
        startActivity(GoToOption);
        break;  
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

and this is the Service form:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

/*@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    ListenSMS();
}*/

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    ListenSMS();
    // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
    // stopped, so return sticky.
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void ListenSMS() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    messageList  = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, messageList);

    //Toast.makeText(this, "Masuk bagian sini sudah", 1).show();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
    registerReceiver(receiver_SMS, filter);
}

BroadcastReceiver receiver_SMS = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
         if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED))
         {
                Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                if (bundle != null)
                {
                  Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                  SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                  for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                  for (SmsMessage message : messages)
                  {
                         Toast.makeText(ListenSMSservice.this, "isi pesan >> "+message.getDisplayMessageBody(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                         receivedMessage(message.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
                         if (message.getDisplayMessageBody().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("aaaa"))
                         {
                             Toast.makeText(ListenSMSservice.this, "messegenya aaaa", 1).show();
                         }
                  }
                }
              }
    }
};
private void receivedMessage(String message)
{
    messageList.add(message);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Unfortunately, my service can be stopped by Advanced task killer, so I can't listen for the SMS command.

I'm using `start_sticky` option, but it does not work for me.
Does anyone have an idea how to handle that problem, so I can listen to the SMS (auto started service) even when task killer was used to kill my application?

Comment: If a user force-stops your application via a 3rd party tool or the settings menu, then they want it to be stopped.

Comment: yes, of course.. but i make a security application. my application should works if the device was stolen or lost. my application can lock the android device so the thief can't access the phone. if my service can be stopped, how to prevent the lost phone for being accessed by the thief?? any solution?? thanks..

Comment: You claim to be making a "security service". It is just as possible that you are creating malware, since malware can have the features that you describe. Android defends users against malware, which means it defends users against your "security service". There are better solutions for defending users against lost/stolen/seized phones (e.g., whole disk encryption) that are (or could be) part of the OS.

Comment: this is my final project. i create an application like mcafee wave secure.. if you say that i creating a malware, how about mcafee wave secure??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> anyone have idea how to handle that problem, so i can listen to the SMS (auto started service) while task killer have killed my application

If the user force-stops your application via Settings or a task killer, the user is saying that your app is not supposed to run. Please honor and respect that decision.

As of Android 3.1, your application will not run again after being force-stopped, until the user launches it again from an activity.

Comment: **"If the user force-stops your application via Settings or a task killer, the user is saying that your app is not supposed to run. Please honor and respect that decision."** >> i make a security application that can lock an android phone when it lost or stolen, so the thief can't access that phone.. if my application can be stopped, then how i can secure the android phone?? any solution?

Comment: @CommonsWare could you please add link references from android site about: "As of Android 3.1, your application will not run again after being force-stopped, until the user launches it again from an activity"

Answer (score 4):

Register a `<reciver>` in the manifest and it will start your app when you receive a SMS

```
<receiver android:name=".YourBroadCastReciver" android:enabled="true">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: This will not help the OP's problem, starting with Android 3.1. A force-stopped application will not respond to broadcasts until the user launches an activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare after the activity is first launched the broadcasts will be received normaly ?

Comment: @opc0de: Yes, unless the user goes into Settings and clicks "Force Stop" for the app. Then you are back in the same state as you were when the app was first installed.